# How to convert MLMultiArray to UIImage?

Tags: ios, coreml

I'm trying to run CoreML model, that produce image as MLMultiArray and I want to display it.
Could anyone share code on swift that converts MLMultiArray to UIImage?

Comment: I'd be happy to whip something up and put it into the CoreMLHelpers repo. What is the shape of your MLMultiArray?

Comment: CoreMLHelpers is cool! The shape of my MLMultiArray is [C, H, W] and it would be usefull to convert to [H, W, C] (and vice versa), and convert to UIImage. Is it possible to convert it on GPU.

Comment: OK, just pushed an update with a basic MLMultiArray to UIImage conversion method. https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers

Comment: Double 1 x 1 x 22 x 40 x 40 array

My OutPut is this, Can you guide me to produce image from this MLMultiArray